# How can i create url in a yii web app

Tags: php, yii

I have a yii 1.x project and i want to create a custom url.
This is my link:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
array('label'=>'Kapcsolat', 'url'=>array('/site/contact','lang'=>'hu')),
        ),
        )); ?>
```

This is my url manager:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'site/contact',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',              
    ),
                'showScriptName'=>false,
),
```

And this is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

I would like to create an url like this: www.domain.com/custom/hu
And if i GET another "lang" like "?lang=en" I would create an url like this: www.domain.com/custom2/en

Comment: Have you atleast tried changing URLManager configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another line to accept language:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<lang:\w>'=>'<controller>/<action>&language=<lang>',
```